# Using Regex to get jsessionid

Tags: java, regex

I have to get the jsessionid code from an url not the jsessionid string. It is possible to match something and exclude it?

https://esgf-data.dkrz.de/esgf-idp/idp/login.htm;jsessionid=436100313FAFBBB9B4DC8BA3C2EC267B

```
Result = 436100313FAFBBB9B4DC8BA3C2EC267B
```

Code added from comment:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("/jsessionid=([a-z0-9]+)/i"); 
Matcher matcher=pattern.matcher(connection.getURL().toExternalForm());
```

Comment: What have you tried? also what language are you using to read the url, because you can probably parse the url and get the parameter without RegExp

Comment: `/jsessionid=([a-z0-9]+)/i` Should do the job.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I'm developing it with Java. Sorry for the missunderstood. I tried this:

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("/jsessionid=([a-z0-9]+)/i");
Matcher matcher=pattern.matcher(connection.getURL().toExternalForm());

Comment: you don't need `[a-z]` here since it's hex, so `[a-f0-9]` is sufficient and optimum for validation

Comment: I've tried the code above but matcher.find() and matcher.matches() return false.

Answer (score 0):

`/=([A-Z0-9]+)/` will get all uppercase and numbers after the equals sign `=` and move them to backreference #1

```
$subject = 'https://esgf-data.dkrz.de/esgf-idp/idp/login.htm;jsessionid=436100313FAFBBB9B4DC8BA3C2EC267B';
if (preg_match('/=([A-Z0-9]+)/', $subject, $regs)) {
    $result = $regs[1];
} else {
    $result = "";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Unamata but it seems not to work. I tested your regular expression on regexpal.com and it doesn't catch the code. I developing with Java and Pattern/Matcher but even with =([A-Z0-9]+) the matcher doesn't match anything.

Comment: @user2032199: It should, if you use `find()` rather than `matches()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this out :

```
    String data = "https://esgf-data.dkrz.de/esgf-idp/idp/login.htm;jsessionid=436100313FAFBBB9B4DC8BA3C2EC267B";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("jsessionid=(\\w+)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(data);

    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println("Result is : " + matcher.group(1));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as a caveat if you have a routing identifier [1](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/reference/workers.html) [2](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/engine.html) on the end of your JSESSIONID, these previous regular expressions might fail.  I found this will pick up the routing expression as well ([Regex101](http://regex101.com/r/iB5cW9/2)).

```
^([A-F0-9]+)((\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*)$
```