# RegEx help: get jsessionid through regex

Tags: regex

I need to cut out the JSESSION id from cookie values. Basically what I want is in a text like:

```
foo bar JSESSIONID_TH=ABCDEF; bar foo
```

I want to get ABCDEF through a regex.

I checked [Match Sequence using RegEx After a Specified Character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10768924/match-sequence-using-regex-after-a-specified-character) and [Using Regex to get jsessionid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15520344/using-regex-to-get-jsessionid) and currently have this regex:

```
(?<=JSESSIONID)[^;]+
```

I thought about give me everything between JSESSION and the following ";" as a start. However, this regex is not working. In addition the `JSESSIONID_TH` can also be `JSESSIONID_FC` so for either or it should give me the value after the equals sign.
I appreciate any help and idea.

Best regards,

Dennis

Comment: Which language are you running?

Comment: Hi, internal Java RegEx implementation

Comment: Can't you use the standard [`request.getCookies()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getCookies()) method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below regex(which uses capturing group) and get the value of `JSESSIONID` from group index 1.

```
JSESSIONID[^;=]*=([^;]+)
```

Answer (score 0):

`\s*JSESSIONID.*?=([^;]+)`

For `<optional space>JESESSION<anything until first =><capture><until ;>`

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot. This is working but only if there is a space before JSESSIONID which is not always the case. any idea how to face this? Thanks!

Comment: Edited, don't know why \b fails.  Others subsequently removed \b which would cause ANYTHINGJSESSION to match.

Comment: Thank you Alex for your help and your time